# Best practice to creating View layer in MVP GWT

Tags: design-patterns, gwt, mvp, gwt-mvp

I red google-gwt article about [MVP](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html)
and would like to ask about how you are creating the view layer.
Suppose you have three different "elements" on one view, the Tree, the Table and Text.
And now I think the best practice is to create these three elements decoupled 
(I mean that, if I don't want Tree "element", in my view, I would comment the line, with for instance setTree(...) in code, somewhere).
Also I would like to use UIBinder for creating each of the "element"

So my questions are:
Who should be responsible for creating such decoupled element like Tree or Table (Controller, Presenter or may View)

and

Who is responsible for setting such elements to the View?

Comment: By "view" here, do you mean "the whole screen"? If so, then you should read [Activities and Places](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) (and code each activity using MVP). Another highly-recommended reading about MVP: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/gwt-continuous-build-testing.html

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. I'm still diging this issue and I can't understend where should I keep/serve events in that project. Whether is to this some smart practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view should be responsible for assembling the widget components it needs.  Your view class will be the one with a corresponding UiBinder file, and in that file you can combine a Tree, Table, and Label (or whatever).